# TesseractNotFound - Pytesser

Tags: python, python-2.7, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to do OCR using pytesser downloaded from [HERE](https://github.com/RobinDavid/Pytesser).

Here is the code of pytesser.py

```
try:
    import cv2.cv as cv
    OPENCV_AVAILABLE = True
except ImportError:
    OPENCV_AVAILABLE = False

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

PROG_NAME = 'tesseract'
TEMP_IMAGE = 'tmp.bmp'
TEMP_FILE = 'tmp'

#All the PSM arguments as a variable name (avoid having to know them)
PSM_OSD_ONLY = 0
PSM_SEG_AND_OSD = 1
PSM_SEG_ONLY = 2
PSM_AUTO = 3
PSM_SINGLE_COLUMN = 4
PSM_VERTICAL_ALIGN = 5
PSM_UNIFORM_BLOCK = 6
PSM_SINGLE_LINE = 7
PSM_SINGLE_WORD = 8
PSM_SINGLE_WORD_CIRCLE = 9
PSM_SINGLE_CHAR = 10

class TesseractException(Exception): #Raised when tesseract does not return 0
    pass

class TesseractNotFound(Exception): #When tesseract is not found in the path
    pass

def check_path(): #Check if tesseract is in the path raise TesseractNotFound otherwise
    for path in os.environ.get('PATH', '').split(';'):
        filepath = os.path.join(path, PROG_NAME)
        if os.path.exists(filepath) and not os.path.isdir(filepath):
            return True
    raise TesseractNotFound

def process_request(input_file, output_file, lang=None, psm=None):
    args = [PROG_NAME, input_file, output_file] #Create the arguments
    if lang is not None:
        args.append("-l")
        args.append(lang)
    if psm is not None:
        args.append("-psm")
        args.append(str(psm))
    proc = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) #Open process
    ret = proc.communicate() #Launch it

    code = proc.returncode
    if code != 0:
        if code == 2:
            raise TesseractException, "File not found"
        if code == -11:
            raise TesseractException, "Language code invalid: "+ret[1]
        else:
            raise TesseractException, ret[1]

def iplimage_to_string(im, lang=None, psm=None):
    if not OPENCV_AVAILABLE:
        print "OpenCV not Available"
        return -1
    else:
        cv.SaveImage(TEMP_IMAGE, im)
        txt = image_to_string(TEMP_IMAGE, lang, psm)
        os.remove(TEMP_IMAGE)
        return txt

def image_to_string(file,lang=None, psm=None):
    check_path() #Check if tesseract available in the path
    process_request(file, TEMP_FILE, lang, psm) #Process command
    f = open(TEMP_FILE+".txt","r") #Open back the file
    txt = f.read()
    os.remove(TEMP_FILE+".txt")
    return txt


if __name__ =='__main__':
    print image_to_string("image.jpg", "fra", PSM_AUTO) #Example
```

The problem is, when I try to execute the sample snippet provided in the above link, I get the error `Tesseract

```
>>> import pytesser
>>> txt = pytesser.image_to_string('C:/output.png')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    txt = pytesser.image_to_string('C:/output.png')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesser.py", line 71, in image_to_string
    check_path() #Check if tesseract available in the path
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesser.py", line 38, in check_path
    raise TesseractNotFound
TesseractNotFound
>>>
```

my [Tesseract-OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list) installation is in `C:\Tesseract-OCR`

I have set the `TESSDATA_PREFIX=C:\Tesseract-OCR\` 
also `Path=C:\Tesseract-OCR`

I want to know why I'm getting `TessractnotFound` despite having correct environment variables set?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you get if you run `print os.environ.get('PATH', '')`?

Comment: @RobWatts Thanks for the reply, actually the problem is solved now, had to make some changes in `pytesser.py` , will post them now.

Answer (score 1):

Following changes in `pytesser.py` solved my problem, there is no problem with the paths that are set.

Changes are as follows:

`PROG_NAME=tesseract` changed to `PROG_NAME=tesseract.exe`

In the function `image_to_string()` added `f.close()` after `txt=f.read()`

That't it :)